# How do you say "root beer"?

Tags: translation, accusative

So I'm struggling a bit with the accusatives and saying "root beer" is confusing me a bit. *Root* is *radiko*, and *beer* is *biero*. Do I say *radiko biero*, *radikon bieron*, or *radiko bieron*? Or is it something completely different?

Comment: The title makes this seem like a vocabulary question, but the body of the question seems to be about grammar. Could you clarify what it is you would like to know?

Comment: You cannot combine two nouns like that. One has to be an adjective.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest combining the two into a compound word: either *radikbiero* or *radik-biero* (the latter makes the roots clearer). You could also possibly say *radika biero*, but not *radiko biero*, since *radik'* is describing and qualifying *biero*.

As for accusative forms, adjectives are declined in the same way as the nouns they describe, so the accusative form of *radika biero* would just be *radikan bieron*. Only endings change, so the accusative of *radik-biero* would be *radik-bieron*.

Answer (score 7):

An international language will always struggle to express purely national concepts - and regional foods and beverages fall strongly into this category. Root Beer is very much an American phenomenon and has not been widely exported like cola and fanta have been. Consequently, one should not expect Esperanto to have a good expression for this - certainly not one that will resonate with anybody not familiar with American culture and the English language.

You'll find suggestions in bilingual dictionaries such as *radikbiero* or *sasafrasaĵo*, but use them with caution - and be prepared to explain what they're supposed to mean. (Maybe even include the regional name "root beer.")

I also found these links useful:

Kiel traduki "root beer"?
http://www.argilo.net/node/73

Kiel traduki "root beer"?
http://argilo.livejournal.com/10203.html?thread=16347

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest simply checking [Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radikbiero) for concepts like these. It suggests "Radikbiero".

In a compound word like this, the o just takes an -n in the accusative form:

*Radikbiero estas bongusta.*

*Usonanoj trinkas radikbieron.*

As others have said, if it were a concept translated with a noun and an adjective, both the noun and the adjective would take the -n, after the a and the o, respectively:

*Radikbiero estas senalkohola trinkaĵo.*

*Mi preferas senalkoholan trinkaĵon.*

Comment: Be careful when using Vikipedio for vocabulary when the article in question is not a well-established article. This one contains the warning *Ĉi tiu artikolo ankoraŭ estas ĝermo.* There is no "discussion" of the article. The edit history seems to be mostly visits from robots - plus a small spelling correction and a small vocabulary correction. In this case, Vikipedio agrees with at least some bilingual dictionaries, but generally, the first place you'll want to check is a published dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

*Root* in *root beer* is not different from *solar* in *solar system*: Both are attributes.
In Esperanto, when translating *root beer*, you add the adjectival affix to the Esperanto words for *root*. So, *root beer* is translated as *radika biero* or *radikbiero*, in the same way *solar system* is translated as *suna sistemo* or *sunsistemo*.

For the accusative, you add the *-n* affix to the attribute and the noun. So, the accusative of *radika biero* is *radikan bieron*, while the accusative of *radikbiero* is *radikbieron*.